# Core Data issue turning a cocoa pod into a local framework

Tags: ios, core-data, cocoapods

So I recently took over a project and the former dev had created a service/persistence API that was a cocoapod. As it is never going to be used in any other project I decided to integrate it into the main project as a separate project(framework) in the workspace. The issue is that the core data layer existed in the API pod and now I moving it into the workspace.

I am running into this error:

> Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code 
>       generation: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 “No current 
>       version for model at path 
>       /Users/ABC/projects/path/Path/Model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld:” UserInfo= 
>       {NSFilePath=/Users/ABC/projects/path/Path/Model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld, 
>       NSLocalizedDescription=No current version for model at path 
>       /Users/ABC/projects/path/Path/Model/MyModel.xcdatamodeld:}

When I first run the project on a device that already had the app on it. What do I need to do to update current user's devices to the new file path? Any thoughts? The project will run fine after you delete the app and reinstall with the new version

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Hmmm, if I remember correctly I needed to add the new library as an imbedded binary to the project.